# Return an object that is an instanceof a string

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, instanceof

I am creating a Dependency Injection factory class which allows me to rewrite instances outside and inside the class without having to keep overwriting it.

The issue I have is when I call the `instanceof` on the object referring the namespace like so:

```
if($nsp instanceof $obj)
{
    return $obj::getInstance();
}
```

It always returns false. For example, if there is a Test object inside the namespace `\App\Com` it would still return false. ([See it working properly here](https://3v4l.org/knhjm))

If you cannot visit the above link, I have a `protected $_case` which holds an array of pre-instanced objects. Then the method looks like this:

```
public function using($nsp)
{
    foreach($this->_case as $obj)
    {
        if($nsp instanceof $obj)
        {
            return $obj::getInstance();
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception("Call to $nsp did not match any libraries.");
}
```

And can be called / used like this:

```
Service::getInstance()->using('SomeNamespace\SomeObject');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) explains this concept deeper.

Comment: Down-vote? Explain how this question is asked wrong rather than just down-voting, so I can improve it.

Comment: `$obj` is an *instance* of a class (it could be any class), `$nsp` is a string which holds the *namespace* and *class name* like `\App\Com\Foo`.. I want to basically use that string to check the array of objects and return the corresponding instance @deceze [see what i mean](https://3v4l.org/knhjm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test boils down to this:

```
'SomeNamespace\SomeObject' instanceof $someObj
```

Well, a string is never an instance of a class. It appears you have the operands backwards, and what you want is:

```
if ($obj instanceof $nsp)
```

Comment: appreciated, I've been Googling this for ages. Maybe I'm just having one of them dumb days, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around:

```
if ($obj instanceof $nsp)
```